# HTML Javascript simple validation form with maths function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple inventory webpage with items used/issued to get subtracted from total stock and the should be in multiples of 50, All working fine except a small glitch.
The Javascript isn't giving me balance, its adding the items fine in total variable, calculating and showing if its multiple of 50 or not. All Good.

BUT

just not giving me balance. What has gone wrong? I checked many time but to me all seems fine and in place. Help Please.

```js
function findTotal() {

  var stock = document.getElementsByName('stock');
  var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[name="vala"], [name="valb"], [name="valc"]'); //manual selection of names
  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;

  if ((tot % 50) == 0) {
    document.getElementById('new').value = "correct";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('new').value = "incorrect";
  }
  return tot;
  var bal = number(stock - tot);
  document.getElementById('balance').value = bal;
  return bal;
}

function ValidateTotal() {
  var y = findTotal();
  if ((y % 50) == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Total Must be in multiples of 50");
    return false;

  }
}
```

```html
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" onsubmit="return ValidateTotal(this)" method="post" action="portal.php" class="simple-form">
  <span class="contact100-form-title">
                        Portal <br><span style="color:red;"><span style="font-size: 80%"> Data Submission for '.$datadate.' </red>
                    </span></span>
  </span>

  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Value 1">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="vala" id="vala" placeholder="Value A">


  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Value 2">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="valb" id="valb" placeholder="Value B">

  </div>


  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Value 3">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="valc" id="valc" placeholder="Value C">

  </div>

  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Value 4">
    <input class="input100" type="number" step="1" name="vald" id="vald" placeholder="Value D not in total">

  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Total">
    <input class="input100" type="number" step="1" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Total ABC">

  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="stock">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="stock" id="stock" placeholder="Total Stock">

  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="balance">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="balance" id="balance" placeholder="balance">

  </div>


  <span style="color:red;">Total : 
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="2" readonly="readonly">Validations : 
<input type="text" name="new" id="new" size="5" readonly="readonly"></span></span>

  </div>

  <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
    <button class="contact100-form-btn">
                            Submit
                        </button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you're using `type="number"`, you can use `.valueAsNumber` to bypass the JS parsing to number.

Comment: @evolutionxbox : i did that var bal = number(stock-tot); not working, initially even used without this, same results.

Comment: The code in the comment is not what I suggested, besides the comment wasn't an answer.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry, i'm a noob when it comes to javascript. thats why didn't get your point. I'll search and try "use .valueAsNumber to bypass the JS parsing to number." . Thanks for pointers.

Comment: `return tot;` returns from the function, nothing what's written after that line will run. I'm not aware of a function called `number()` by the way.

Comment: I assume you meant `Number()` not `number()`?

Comment: @tevemadar : included that before ``return tot;`` but still same. And removed number() and used parseInt() instead, but still stuck on same

Comment: `stock` is a collection of HTML elements (even if it probably has a single one here), `stock - tot` could rather be `stock[0].valueAsNumber - tot`, without any `*umber()` call. It may be worth pointing out here that while `name`+`getElementsByName()` may seem a nice thing, it gets element***s*** in a collection. While there's a thing `id`, and `getElementById()`, which gets a single element (with the `id`).

Comment: @evolutionxbox , @tevemadar : Yes ``Number()``, not ``number()``, that was typo.

Comment: @tevemadar : got it, so its using it as an array and not single element, so call has to be towards first element [0], not as whole array.

Comment: @tevemadar : WOW, it worked, Thanks a bunch.
- removed ``Number()`` that was changed to ``ParseInt()`` 
- added array identifier [0], 
and all Great now. Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use getElementsByName because with `getElementsByName` it gives you nodelist.in that case you have specify the index:

`getElementsByName("stock")[0]`.

i changed it to `document.getElementById('stock').value;` getting the value straight from here so you woulnt need to `parseInt` or `.valueAsNumber`.

`var bal = stock - tot;` this will work fine

```js
function findTotal() {

  var stock = document.getElementById('stock').value;/*<-------byId*/
  var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[name="vala"], [name="valb"], [name="valc"]'); //manual selection of names
  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;

  if ((tot % 50) == 0) {
    document.getElementById('new').value = "correct";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('new').value = "incorrect";
  }
  
  var bal = stock - tot;
  document.getElementById('balance').value = bal;
  return bal;
  return tot;
}

function ValidateTotal() {
  var y = findTotal();
  if ((y % 50) == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Total Must be in multiples of 50");
    return false;

  }
}
```

```html
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" onsubmit="return ValidateTotal(this)" method="post" action="portal.php" class="simple-form">
  <span class="contact100-form-title">
                        Portal <br><span style="color:red;"><span style="font-size: 80%"> Data Submission for '.$datadate.' </red>
                    </span></span>
  </span>

  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Value 1">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="vala" id="vala" placeholder="Value A">


  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Value 2">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="valb" id="valb" placeholder="Value B">

  </div>


  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Value 3">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="valc" id="valc" placeholder="Value C">

  </div>

  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Value 4">
    <input class="input100" type="number" step="1" name="vald" id="vald" placeholder="Value D not in total">

  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Total">
    <input class="input100" type="number" step="1" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Total ABC">

  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="stock">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="stock" id="stock" placeholder="Total Stock">

  </div>
  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="balance">
    <input class="input100" onblur="findTotal()" type="number" step="1" name="balance" id="balance" placeholder="balance">

  </div>


  <span style="color:red;">Total : 
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="2" readonly="readonly">Validations : 
<input type="text" name="new" id="new" size="5" readonly="readonly"></span></span>

  </div>

  <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
    <button class="contact100-form-btn">
                            Submit
                        </button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```